# How to specify muliple doc libraries in "Custom Send To Destination"

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I have specified one destination document library in "**Custom Send To Destination**" option of source document library. I can able to send document to this destination library.

But we want to send document to **multiple destination libraries**. How we can achieve this functionality? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use PowerShell to implement your requirement.

Comment: can you please provide related article link if you know.

Comment: http://get-spscripts.com/2010/10/change-sharepoint-list-settings-using.html                                                                                                     You have to set a destination name and URL of the custom Send To location:
you can iterate through the document libraries within the sub sites and set the sendtolocation using array /hashtable in PowerShell.
$list.SendToLocationName = "Home Site"
$list.SendToLocationUrl = "http://Portal/Shared Documents"